# Should a question be closed as duplicate of another when it is asking for the same goal but via a different route?

Tags: discussion, support, duplicates, closed-questions

I recently [closed a question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/719870/compile-unity-without-launcher) as a duplicate [of another](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38009/how-do-i-remove-the-unity-launcher), however I am starting to think that I may have made a mistake here along with the other close voters...

So just to make it easier, let's refer to the question which was closed as the duplicate of another as **Q1**, and the question which it was closed against as **Q2**.

Now, although Q1 is wanting the same goal as Q2, it is asking for it via a different route, and Q1 has an accepted answer which explains how to do it via this route, whereas Q2 has an accepted answer which says that it is not possible through the assumed means of configuration (though it does not exactly specify a route, but just editing it out of Unity's source code manually is probably not assumed).

So if anything, I'm starting to think that Q2 should be made as a duplicate of Q1, or maybe even have them merged, because it doesn't really seem right to mark Q1 as a duplicate of Q2 where Q1 actually does a better job of fixing the problem than Q2.

So, what should be done about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes questions are closed as duplicates of other questions because of the underlying XY problem, which usually works well both for the OP and for the other users of the question.

However in that case OP wanted to address specifically the compilation of Unity without the launcher from source, so the questions are not the same: the most it could be said is that Q2 is a superset of Q1.

However in this case I think they're better off if separated; maybe someone has something else to say about Q1.

Additionally is to be noted that Q1 is linked in Q2 by [other means](https://askubuntu.com/a/723480/380067), so it's easy to access a method to compile Unity without the launcher from source starting from Q2.

So I vote to reopen Q1 and to *not* merge it with Q2.

Comment: Good answer, but what about the fact that Q1 actually has an answer which removes the Unity Launcher, and Q2 does not, and instead says that it is not possible? I actually think that the one about compiling Unity code should be posted as an answer to Q2, that would make the most sense to me anyway...

Comment: @ParanoidPanda "Not possible" is a matter of semantics, most of the answers on Q2 effectively provide a method to *hide* (rather than to remove, ok) the launcher, which is acceptable by most of the audience. Nonetheless that's not an issue anymore: http://askubuntu.com/a/723480/380067. Also in this case If we want the two questions to stay separated I think it's also acceptable to link Q1 in an answer to Q2.