# Duplicate vs Linked vs Related. Best practice for site navigation

Tags: discussion, duplicates, flagging, moderation

I believe that it is very beneficial for related questions to be linked together for easy navigation.  When you use the duplicate tag, it has the benefit of linking questions together even if the question does not get closed.

My question: Should we use the duplicate flag somewhat liberally, to link similar questions even if the questions are not *exactly* the same?  Or should a duplicate flag be reserved only if you feel the question has an exact match and it should be closed?

I was advised the best place for related questions to show up is under "related".  I agree, except I can't figure out how to link a question as "related".  If not currently possible, it would be a good feature to be able to manually link "related" questions if duplicate flags are not to be used in this way.

See: [The question I am referring to](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1159851/how-can-i-make-a-19-04-persistent-live-usb-from-windows)

Comment: I tend to use a comment for that.

Comment: Just like this: [Related](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14967/should-a-question-be-closed-as-duplicate-of-another-when-it-is-asking-for-the-sa)  **;-)**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do not want to close the question as a duplicate, then *do not* use the duplicate flag. Simply leave a comment with the link to the related question instead, then it would appear under the '**Linked**' section at the right.

Once you flag the question, it goes to the [close vote review queue](https://askubuntu.com/review/close/) (accessible to users with 3000+ rep) and then it requires action from multiple reviewers. There is already a huge backlog of posts in this queue, *do not* clog it more with unintended posts.

Comment: Just some extra details: Linked questions can appear anywhere in a Q&A post not just in comments. They can be in a comment, because of a duplicate, in an answer, or even in the question itself. Also, even if the comment, answer, etc. were to be deleted, or the link to the question was edited out, the linked question will always be there.